# Issue Making FizzBuzz

Tags: python, python-3.x, fizzbuzz

Rules of FizzBuzz

> Players generally sit in a circle. The player designated to go first
>   says the number "1", and each player thenceforth counts one number in
>   turn. However, any number divisible by three is replaced by the word
>   fizz and any number divisible by five by the word buzz. Numbers
>   divisible by 15 become fizz buzz.

My attempt

```
x = 0
if x % 3:
    print("fizz")
elif x % 5:
    print("buzz")
else:
    x+=1
```

Comment: [One of many search results](https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/python-conditional-exercise-10.php).

Comment: What is the issue, exactly?

Comment: This is not even a question.  Where are all the other close votes?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out the [tour]. SO is not a tutorial site. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure if your asking for advice on your code or examples of how others have done it but here is mine from when I first started learning python. If you want some info on how it it works feel free to ask.

```
for num in range(0,101):
        if num%3 ==0 and num%5 ==0:
            print("fizzbuzz")
        elif num%3 ==0:
            print("fizz")
        elif num%5 ==0:
            print("buzz")
        else :
            print(num)
```